# Is there a way to set sublime text's key binding in Matlab.?

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

Matlab is currently using windows default key bindings.
Precisely, I would like to know if there's a way to export Matlab compatible key-bindings .xml file from sublime-text?